# Como escrever testes para uma chamada de API Externa?

Tags: python, api, testes, sdk, tdd

Estou pesquisando sobre Unit Testing e TDD e queria aplicar isso a alguns scripts que tenho desenvolvido. A questão é que esses scripts criam dados em um serviço externo, chamando métodos da API, por exemplo:

```
project = sdk.create_project(body=models.WriteProject(
                                    name="test-project"))
```

Ao rodar um teste que chama esse método, seria criado *realmente* um novo projeto? É possível testar a chamada mas não concluir, de fato, a criação do objeto?

É uma dúvida mais conceitual, mas caso necessário para exemplificar, estou trabalhando com Python.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Você pode pesquisar por **mock**.

Comment: @Leila recomendo esse livro que acabou de sair do forno do Alessandro Molina é sensacional (principalmente porque vc está usando Python): https://www.packtpub.com/product/crafting-test-driven-software-with-python/9781838642655

Na prática, instale o Postman, crie uma conta lá e crie um servidor MOCK (que SIMULE, respostas da API - para ser direto ao ponto é um servidor de enfeite que devolve saídas que vc deverá configurar) é uma sugestão rápida e fácil para vc simular o comportamento de respostas de uma API. Eu uso muito e recomendo

Comment: @Mateus obrigada, o livro parece bom, vou pesquisar mais sobre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não deve testar a API externa, pois isso está fora do seu controle. O que você deve testar é **o que seu código faz, dado o(s) comportamento(s) que a API externa pode apresentar**.

Por exemplo, vamos dizer que sua função `get_project` cria e retorna um objeto criado pela API externa. Você sabe que, se forem passados os parâmetros errados, a API vai lançar uma exceção do tipo `SomeExternalAPIException`. Então você escreve seu código para lidar com isso usando um try/except, e retornando `None` no caso de erro:

```
import api_externa

def get_project(
    params: Dict[str, Any],
) -> Optional[api_externa.Project]:
    """
    Cria um projeto novo usando a API externa e o retorna.
    Pode retornar None caso parâmetros inválidos sejam 
    passados para a API externa.
    """
    try:
        project = api_externa.create_project(params=params)
        return project
    except SomeExternalAPIException:
        return None
```

No seu teste, você não precisa testar se a API funciona como você espera (isso é função dos desenvolvedores da API). Você testa apenas se seu código retorna de fato o objeto da API quando parâmetros sabidamente válidos são entregues a ela, e se retorna `None` caso contrário:

```
import unittest

import api_externa

from myapp import get_project

class TestMyApp(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_project_returns_a_project_when_params_are_valid(self):
        """
        Testa se a função get_project retorna uma instância de 
        api_externa.Project quando são passados parâmetros válidos 
        a ela
        """
        params = { ... }  # parâmetros válidos aqui
        returned_value = get_project(params=params)
        self.assertIsInstance(returned_value, api_externa.Project)

    def test_get_project_returns_none_when_params_are_invalid(self):
        """
        Testa se a função get_project retorna None
        quando são passados parâmetros inválidos a ela
        """
        params = { ... }  # parâmetros inválidos aqui
        returned_value = get_project(params=params)
        self.assertIsNone(returned_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Se você precisa **controlar/simular algum aspecto da API externa** (por exemplo, a API se conecta a web para acessar alguns dados, e você precisa simular uma queda na conexão para um dos testes), aí você precisará usar **mocks**, que são uma forma de criar objetos arbitrários que substituem qualquer elemento da APi durante um teste. Nesse caso, sugiro começar lendo a [documentação de Python para mocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).